# PDF Printing with large text in a table cell spilling into th

Tags: css, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, page-break, page-break-inside

I have a pdf report generated using wkhtmltopdf. Part of it is a table with a HTML comments which could get as long as 3 pages. I already have the below CSS to avoid any table row or table cell having a page-break inside, which works well for smaller rows. However, in case of the row with large comment, the cell spans across multiple pages and spilling into the table header on the next page.

How can I make the overflown text sit inside the cell instead of overlapping the header on the next page?

```css
thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot {
    display: table-row-group;
}

tr, td, th, .dont-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Because I have the same

Comment: The problem seems to be browser specific. Since wkhtml2pdf uses the webkit browser, it doesn't seem to recognise some the page-break related styling. I switched to a puppeteer to generate the pdf files, which uses head-less chrome to render PDF.